# Redirect to Home.aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to redirect to `Home.aspx` when project load  first time, but whatever I did or change in web.config file still redirect to `Login.aspx`!

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear/>
    <add value="Home.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>

<location path="Login.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<location path="Home.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

See `path="*."` if I make it like `path="Home.aspx"` it will redirect to Home.aspx but database in entire project will be hidden. The question is what does make the website always redirect to `Login.aspx` and what is the best way to force website to redirect to Home.aspx when start as first time?

Thanks

Comment: It may be because you are using Forms Authentication and that is the default redirect?

Comment: Yeah, I am using Forms Authentication, and the try to redirect to `default.aspx` which requires user authentication. How to disable default redirection and set a new redirection

Comment: If i understand your question correctly then you can try this - In iis you can set **default documents** to `Home.aspx`, if you already publish your web site. In visual studio you can set startup page.

Comment: That should not be an issue, but just in case, have you tried `<allow users="*" />`?

Answer (score 0):

**Try Form Authentication** 
In Web.config write

```
</configuration>
   <system.web>
        <!--Session state Time Out-->
        <sessionState timeout="60" /> 
        <!--My authontication module-->
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms name="WSMSCRM.ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Login/Login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60"/>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <!--location add-->
        <!--End of Authontication-->
    </system.web>

<!--Rest is ommited-->
  <location path="~/Login/Login.aspx">
    <system.web>

      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>

      </authorization>
    </system.web>

  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Brother try this in webconfig file....mine was resolved with  this...

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Home.aspx"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```